# Android OEM Unlock wipe taking too long

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader-lock

Im using Oneplus 3T and when I did `fastboot oem unlock`
now my device is stuck on screen since last 30mins plus
"Wiping, please wait"

How long one should wait ? any way I can exit this and start again ?

Comment: On encrypted devices this takes just a second as only the cryptographic key is deleted and overwritten. But your device was shipped with Android 6 and most likely without encryption. Therefore oem unlock should cause a complete overwrite.

Comment: please tell us how long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!

My device was already OEM Unlocked enabled.

I powered off my phone. and Simply Booted with TWRP.

```
fastboot boot recovery.img
```

Also I had to wipe the Device using `Ext2` file system under
`Wipe > Advance Wipe > Data > Repair / Change File system`

After this I enabled ADB shell and flashed Havoc OS android 11 on my oneplus 3t.

Everything is working great so far. Also a quick note, for rooting I used `Magisk` and try to get an older version of Magisk this allows you to use `MagiskHide` which is useful for banking apps like Gpay, Jio app.. etc.